# XSL transform of hex code of unicode latin characters

Tags: java, xml, rest, xslt, unicode

I have below input xml:
[InputXml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFTAu.png)

```html
<Person>
    <PersonName>
    <NamePrefix>Mr</NamePrefix>
    <FirstName>&#xC4;&#x98;Test</FirstName>
    <Lastname>Test</Lastname>
    </PersonName>
    </Person>
```

In above xml there is hex code for Ä followed by hex code for ~.

https://www.codetable.net/hex/c4
https://www.codetable.net/hex/98

I am using below XSL logic:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="./Person">
            <Customer>
                <xsl:for-each select="./PersonName">
                    <PersonName>
                        <NameTitle>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./NamePrefix" />
                        </NameTitle>
                        <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="./FirstName">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="./FirstName" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                          <FirstName ></FirstName>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <Lastname>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./Lastname" />
                        </Lastname>
                    </PersonName>
                </xsl:for-each>
            
            </Person>
        </xsl:for-each>
                                                                
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With above xsl file below XML output is generated

[OutputXML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgiGa.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Person>
<PersonName>
<NamePrefix>Mr</NamePrefix>
<FirstName>Ä&#x98;Test</FirstName>
<Lastname>Test</Lastname>
</PersonName>
</Person>
```

As seen in above output xml the hex code for Ä is converted to actual character, but this is not happening with ~. I want the hex code for ~ to also convert to actual character.

There are many unicode latin characters which also work fine with Hex code. Only problem is for tilde symbol ~, whose hex code is not converting to symbol.

https://factorpad.com/tech/unicode-latin-1.html

Is this issue with XSL file? What is the solution for this?

Comment: The hex code for the tilde character is `&#x7E;`. The code that you have `&#x98;` is for the  START OF STRING control character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: thanks you correcting this. Can you tell me what is use of this START OF STRING character?

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea. Perhaps something to do with controlling a printer or a scanner? Your Google is as good as mine. The point is that it is not displayed as a glyph because there is no glyph for this code.

Comment: x98 in the Windows CP1252 character code is a "small tilde". That's probably what is being represented here. In XML, hex character codes are always supposed to be Unicode codepoint values, but what you have here is a miscoded CP1252 codepoint.